# How to get the css with in inline styles using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am loading the styles dynamically from the database in my asp.net mvc (C#) application.

I am trying to change some of the properties like (background, font color, font size,...) of the loaded inline style. I am using jquery.rule to do this.

I need to update the complete inline style including the changes, back to the database using jquery.

The inline style inside the head looks like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!
    -- body
    {
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font: normal 12px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
        color: #636363;
    }
    a
    {
        color: #d0d0d0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #header
    {
        padding-left: 35px;
        height: 60px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    -- ></style>
```

I need to get updated inline style. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to update the complete inline style including the changes, back to the database using jquery.

Are you trying to read the inline style declarations of an element in the page? If so, this is tricky. In theory you should be able to call `element.getAttribute('style')` or the jQuery equivalent. However DOM attribute access doesn't work in IE; in fact IE doesn't store the attribute as used in the document at all, only the parsed style declarations that result from it.

There's not a jQuery-specific means of reading all styles, but you can get the effective inline style rules as CSS using [DOM Level 2 Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSRule-cssText).

```
var style= element.style.cssText;
```

But in IE this will separate any shortcut properties you have used, for example setting `border` can result in you getting `border-style`, `border-color` and `border-width` back. IE will also upper-case the property names. This may or may not matter to you.

You'd probably be better off remembering the inline style changes you make in a separate lookup object so you can read it more easily. You can attach that to the element using jQuery's `data()` method, make all changes to both the ‘real’ `element.style` and the lookup `$(element).data('stylestore')` objects, then retrieve all set styles from the lookup when you're about to post.

Comment: $('#elementid').css('font', 'arial') to change the class and 
$('#elementid').css('font') to get the class value

Comment: I need to get the updated inline styles of the page. I have updated my question with the sample inline style

Comment: Oh, you mean an internal **stylesheet**, rather than an inline `style` attribute? With the rule plugin that's `$('style').cssText()` (replacing `'style'` with a suitable selector to pick your stylesheet, if you have been using one).

Comment: How can i use the jquery rule to get the internal stylesheet inside an iframe?

Comment: You would have to include another copy of jQuery and Rule plugin in the iframe's document, and script from that copy's version of `$`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the jQuery ajax method to post form serialized data to your action method:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/YourController/UpdateCss",
   data: "font=arial&color=#fff&font-size=10px"
   success: function(result){
      // handle your result here
   }
});
```

You can then access the posted data in your controller action via the "FormCollection":

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public String UpdateCss(FormCollection form)
{
    // handle your form here
    return "Success";
}
```

Hope this helps

-Mark

Comment: I guess you can't build an action with return typ String

Comment: why would you return an ActionResult on an ajax request?? you would most lilely return bool, json, string etc etc...