# Css tool, to calculate how many (in bytes) inline css in html

Tags: css, firebug, inline

There is Firebug AddOn - "Inline Code Finder", but it doesn't show how many bytes! Do you know any tool doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stoyan Stefanov created a really nice tool fr working out the values of js/css on a page and called it statsy

http://www.phpied.com/statsy-more-data-points-for-markup-quality/

Below is an explanation taken from his site

> the results
>
> Once you run the bookmarklet it alerts
>   these stats points:
>
> - - JS attributes (e.g. onclick) - this is the sum of all onclick,
>       onmouseover and so on including the
>       attribute names. So for example  is 11 characters (bytes)
>       of JavaScript attributes code
>   - CSS style attributes - the sum of all style="..."
>   - Inline JS - the sum of all the contents of all script tags (excluding
>       the tag itself)
>   - Inline CSS - sum of all  tag contents
>   - All innerHTML - this is document.documentElement.innerHTML.length,
>       it should be close to the ungzipped
>       size of a page, provided the page is
>       not doing a lot of DOM manipulation
>   - ## DOM elements - the total number of elements on the page is
>
>     counted simply using
>       document.getElementsByTagName('*').length

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following bit of JS in the Firebug Console for the size in bytes of all the [effective inline style rules as CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733992/how-to-get-the-css-with-in-inline-styles-using-jquery/1734123#1734123).

(unhook all linked stylesheets, load page and run this JS to effectively get the only-declared-inline CSS size).

```
var styleText = '';
$('*').each(function(){
    styleText += this.style.cssText;
});
var styleTextLengthInBytes = encodeURIComponent(styleText).replace(/%../g, 'x').length
console.log(styleTextLengthInBytes);
```

(conversion to bytes handles UTF-8 correctly, courtesy of [dt.in.th/2008-09-16.string-length-in-bytes](http://dt.in.th/2008-09-16.string-length-in-bytes.html)

---

Variation - exclude SPANs and Ps, and count everything else:

```
var styleText = '';
$('* :not(span,p)').each(function(){
    styleText += this.style.cssText;
});
var styleTextLengthInBytes = encodeURIComponent(styleText).replace(/%../g, 'x').length
console.log(styleTextLengthInBytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a character count on the found CSS - usually 1 char is 1 byte.